# pandas Auto increment based on date condition

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to auto increment a new column I have the below code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2020-02-29', '2020-03-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-02', '2020-10-03', '2020-10-04', '2021-10-01', '2021-10-02', '2021-10-03', '2021-10-04']})

conditions = [((df['Date'].dt.day == 1) & (df['Date'].dt.month == 10)), ((df['Date'].dt.day == 29) & (df['Date'].dt.month == 2))]
r_choice = [1, 151]

df['Oct_year_day'] = np.select(conditions, r_choice, np.nan)
df['Oct_year_day'] = df['Oct_year_day'].fillna(1).cumsum()

# the below code does not work...
reset_condition = (df['Date'].dt.day == 1) & (df['Date'].dt.month == 10)
df.loc[reset_condition, 'Oct_year_day'] = 1
```

What I want returned is:

```
         Date  Oct_year_day
0  2020-02-29          151.0
1  2020-03-01          152.0 
2  2020-10-01            1.0
3  2020-10-02            2.0
4  2020-10-03            3.0
5  2020-10-04            4.0
6  2021-10-01            1.0
7  2021-10-02            2.0
8  2021-10-03            3.0
9  2021-10-04            4.0
```

*Edit The incrementation.*

So the incrementation would start over every October 1st with 1 and increase by 1 each proceeding date afterword. Think of it like the `df['Date'].dt.dayofyear`. The other part is that the leap day would be 151 and each proceeding date afterword would increase by 1.

Comment: You should detail how would you want the increment to be done, because it is quite unclear.

Comment: @PaulS, Does the addition explanation add clarification?

Comment: And what happens when it's not a leap year? Are 2022-02-28 and 2022-03-01 would be 150 and 151?

Comment: @Corralien, In that case 2022-02-28 and 2022-03-01 would be 151 and 152

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want the day of the year from the first Ictober of the current year:

```
def counter(sr):
    year = sr.name
    oct1 = pd.Timestamp(f'{year}-10-01')
    m = sr < oct1
    return pd.concat([sr[m].sub(oct1-pd.DateOffset(years=1)).dt.days,
                      sr[~m].sub(oct1-pd.DateOffset(days=1)).dt.days])

df['Oct_year_day'] = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year)['Date'].transform(counter)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         Date  Oct_year_day
0  2020-02-29           151
1  2020-03-01           152
2  2020-10-01             1
3  2020-10-02             2
4  2020-10-03             3
5  2020-10-04             4
6  2021-10-01             1
7  2021-10-02             2
8  2021-10-03             3
9  2021-10-04             4
10 2022-02-28           150
11 2022-03-01           151
```